# Highcharts: Difference between onMouseOver vs onContainerPointerMove?

Tags: highcharts

I've noticed that at times the onMouseOver(e) function gets triggered when I hover over my chart but other times the onContainerPointerMove() function gets triggered. How do these 2 differ? What triggers each function? Can the trigger event be changed?

Reference for onContainerPointerMove function: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/MSPointer.js
There doesn't seem to be documentation for the onContainerPointerMove function in the API reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `onContainerPointerMove` is an internal Highcharts function and that is why it is not documented.

As the name suggests, `onMouseOver` is fired when the mouse pointer enters the element or one of its children. `onContainerPointerMove` is called on every poiner move over the element.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I understood this right, when the cursor enters a clickable element and becomes a pointer, the onMouseOver and onContainerPointerMove methods are fired. And while the pointer is on the element, the onContainerPointerMove method is called?

Comment: Hi @user7999116, Yes, `onContainerPointerMove` is called on every pointer move on the element, `onMouseOver` is called only when pointers enters the element.